# Testing whether some code works for ALL input numbers?

Tags: testing, integer, code-coverage

I've got an algorithm using a single (positive integer) number as an input to produce an output.  And I've got the reverse function which should do the exact opposite, going back from the output to the *same* integer number.  This should be a unique one-to-one reversible mapping.

I've tested this for some integers, but I want to be *100%* sure that it works for *all* of them, up to a known limit.

The problem is that if I just test every integer, it takes an unreasonably long time to run.  If I use 64-bit integers, that's a *lot* of numbers to check if I want to check them all.  On the other hand, if I only test every 10th or 100th number, I'm not going to be 100% sure at the end.  There might be some awkward weird constellation in one of the 90% or 99% which I didn't test.

Are there any general ways to identify edge cases so that just those "interesting" or "risky" numbers are checked?  Or should I just pick numbers at random?  Or test in increasing increments?

Or to put the question another way, how can I approach this so that I gain 100% confidence that every case will be properly handled?

Answer (score 0):

The approach for this is generally checking every step of the computation for potential flaws. Concerning integer math, that is overflows, underflows and rounding errors from division, basically that the mathematical result can't be represented accurately. In addition, all operations derived from this suffer similar problems.

The process of auditing then looks at single steps in turn. For example, if you want to allocate memory for N integers, you need N times the size of an integer in bytes and this multiplication can overflow. You now determine those values where the multiplication overflows and create according tests that exercise these. Note that for the example of allocating memory, proper handling typically means that the function does not allocate memory but fail.

The principle behind this is that you determine the ranges for every operation where the outcome is somehow different (like e.g. where it overflows) and then make sure via tests that both variants work. This reduces the number of tests from all possible input values to just those where you expect a significant difference.